# Disable Infragistics Toolbar Button (ButtonTool)

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, infragistics

I need to Enable/Disable the ButtonTool.

Before using Infragistics I used an ordinaly WinForms ToolbarButton, that have a property "Enabled".

I used the databinding like this:

```
UndoButtonTool.DataBindings.Clear()
UndoButtonTool.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", memory, "CanUndo")
```

How can I do now using the infragistics ButtonTool?

doing

```
UndoButtonTool.DataBindings.Clear()
UndoButtonTool.DataBindings.Add("SharedProps.Enabled", memory, "CanUndo")
```

will not work...

I already implemented an custom BindableButtonTool:

```
Public Class ToolStripBindableButton
  Inherits Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ButtonTool
  Implements IBindableComponent

  Private _DataBindings As ControlBindingsCollection
  Private _BindingContext As BindingContext
  Private _Site As System.ComponentModel.ISite

  Public Event DisposedAsStrip As EventHandler Implements IBindableComponent.Disposed

  Sub New(ByVal name As String)
    MyBase.New(name)
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property DataBindings() As ControlBindingsCollection Implements System.Windows.Forms.IBindableComponent.DataBindings
    Get
      If _DataBindings Is Nothing Then
        _DataBindings = New ControlBindingsCollection(Me)
      End If
      Return _DataBindings
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Property BindingContext() As BindingContext Implements System.Windows.Forms.IBindableComponent.BindingContext
    Get
      If _BindingContext Is Nothing Then
        _BindingContext = New BindingContext()
      End If
      Return _BindingContext
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As BindingContext)
      _BindingContext = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Overloads Sub Dispose()
    If _DataBindings IsNot Nothing Then
      _DataBindings.Clear()
      _DataBindings = Nothing
    End If
    _BindingContext = Nothing

    MyBase.Dispose()

    RaiseEvent DisposedAsStrip(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
  End Sub

  Property Site As System.ComponentModel.ISite Implements System.ComponentModel.IComponent.Site
    Get
      Return _Site
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As System.ComponentModel.ISite)
      _Site = value
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Try UndoButtonTool.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", memory.SharedProps, "CanUndo"), it should work. I actively use Infragistics and have binded Enabled property successfully.

Answer (score 2):

To enable/disable an Infragistics ButtonTool you can using the following code

```
myButtonTool.SharedProps.Enabled = True / False
```